# LWC / JS - event.stopPropagation() causing error - [event.stopPropagation is not a function]

Tags: javascript, lws

I got this error in the view
[event.stopPropagation is not a function]

This is the code triggering this error

```
commentHandleChange(event){
  let selectedValue = 'Pitched';
  this.handleStatusChange({ detail: { value: selectedValue } });

handleStatusChange(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
```

I've inherited a very complex legacy LWC implementation.
event.stopPropogation is used a number of times throughout the JS file, so I don't just want to comment out this line.

Meanwhile I'm reading up on stopPropogation, but I'm fairly new to events and bubbling, so it's not making much sense yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleStatusChange` isn't being called with an event, so the method doesn't exist here.

```
this.handleStatusChange({ detail: { value: selectedValue } });
```

Is just calling the method without a "real" event. If you want to maintain that logic, which is reasonable, just add your own method:

```
this.handleStatusChange({ 
  detail: { value: selectedValue }, 
  stopPropagation: () => {} 
});
```

This will do nothing special in this code (`()=>{}`) is just a do-nothing function), but will allow that method to actually stop propagation when handling a real event.